# How can I update an application badge every week?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, badge, week-number

How can I update my application badge every week in background mode.

I am working on a app for week numbers, and my application badge are then current week number, so I want it to updating every week by it self.

How can I do that, I have searched Google through, and I didn't find anything.

Maybe it is simple, but I have never worked in app delegate with all these methods, `UILocalnotifications` or an application badge.

Comment: do you want to set badge no when your localnotification run ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setApplicationIconBadgeNumber to set badge no.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Comment: yes i have it here: [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", intUgeNr]]; but i need it to updating by it self in background every week.. but i dont know how :(

Comment: sorry i send you the wrong one, that was for my badge in my app, here is for application icon badge: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:intUgeNr]; sorry.. :)

Comment: are you setting local notification in every week...?

Comment: nope, i only set [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:intUgeNr]; once i viewWillAppear when i open my app, but i want it to change every week i background, but i dont know how :)

Comment: so just fire a localNotification every week and in app delegate didReceiveLocalNotification method just write your code...[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:intUgeNr];

Comment: Okay I will try, I can not get one to send an even every week, by typing:

`notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;`

Comment: you you can try,,..and for this repeateInterval i am doing R&D